# How to terminate long-running computation (CPU bound task) in Python using asyncio and concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing, python-asyncio, process-pool

> Similar Question (but answer does not work for me): [How to cancel long-running subprocesses running using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325559/how-to-cancel-long-running-subprocesses-running-using-concurrent-futures-proces)

Unlike the question linked above and the solution provided, in my case the computation itself is rather long (CPU bound) and cannot be run in a loop to check if some event has happened.

Reduced version of the code below:

```python
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures as futures
import time

class Simulator:
    def __init__(self):
        self._loop = None
        self._lmz_executor = None
        self._tasks = []
        self._max_execution_time = time.monotonic() + 60
        self._long_running_tasks = []

    def initialise(self):
        # Initialise the main asyncio loop
        self._loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self._loop.set_default_executor(
            futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3))

        # Run separate processes of long computation task
        self._lmz_executor = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)

    def run(self):
        self._tasks.extend(
            [self.bot_reasoning_loop(bot_id) for bot_id in [1, 2, 3]]
        )

        try:
            # Gather bot reasoner tasks
            _reasoner_tasks = asyncio.gather(*self._tasks)
            # Send the reasoner tasks to main monitor task
            asyncio.gather(self.sample_main_loop(_reasoner_tasks))
            self._loop.run_forever()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
        finally:
            self._loop.close()

    async def sample_main_loop(self, reasoner_tasks):
        """This is the main monitor task"""
        await asyncio.wait_for(reasoner_tasks, None)
        for task in self._long_running_tasks:
            try:
                await asyncio.wait_for(task, 10)
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                print("Oops. Some long operation timed out.")
                task.cancel()  # Doesn't cancel and has no effect
                task.set_result(None)  # Doesn't seem to have an effect

        self._lmz_executor.shutdown()
        self._loop.stop()
        print('And now I am done. Yay!')

    async def bot_reasoning_loop(self, bot):
        import math

        _exec_count = 0
        _sleepy_time = 15
        _max_runs = math.floor(self._max_execution_time / _sleepy_time)

        self._long_running_tasks.append(
            self._loop.run_in_executor(
                    self._lmz_executor, really_long_process, _sleepy_time))

        while time.monotonic() < self._max_execution_time:
            print("Bot#{}: thinking for {}s. Run {}/{}".format(
                    bot, _sleepy_time, _exec_count, _max_runs))
            await asyncio.sleep(_sleepy_time)
            _exec_count += 1

        print("Bot#{} Finished Thinking".format(bot))

def really_long_process(sleepy_time):
    print("I am a really long computation.....")
    _large_val = 9729379273492397293479237492734 ** 344323
    print("I finally computed this large value: {}".format(_large_val))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sim = Simulator()
    sim.initialise()
    sim.run()
```

The idea is that there is a main simulation loop that runs and monitors three bot threads. Each of these bot threads then perform some reasoning but also start a really long background process using `ProcessPoolExecutor`, which may end up running longer their own threshold/max execution time for reasoning on things.

As you can see in the code above, I attempted to `.cancel()` these tasks when a timeout occurs. Though this is not really cancelling the actual computation, which keeps happening in the background and the `asyncio` loop doesn't terminate until after all the long running computation have finished.

How do I terminate such long running CPU-bound computations within a method?

> Other similar SO questions, but not necessarily related or helpful:
>
> 1. [asyncio: Is it possible to cancel a future been run by an Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413613/asyncio-is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-future-been-run-by-an-executor)
> 2. [How to terminate a single async task in multiprocessing if that single async task exceeds a threshold time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32703599/how-to-terminate-a-single-async-task-in-multiprocessing-if-that-single-async-tas)
> 3. [Asynchronous multiprocessing with a worker pool in Python: how to keep going after timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991968/asynchronous-multiprocessing-with-a-worker-pool-in-python-how-to-keep-going-aft)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How do I terminate such long running CPU-bound computations within a method?

The approach you tried doesn't work because the futures returned by [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor) are not cancellable. Although asyncio's `run_in_executor` [tries](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3df85404d4bf420db3362eeae1345f2cad948a71/Lib/asyncio/futures.py#L357) to propagate the cancellation, it is simply [ignored](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3df85404d4bf420db3362eeae1345f2cad948a71/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L359) by `Future.cancel` once the task starts executing.

There is no fundamental reason for that. Unlike threads, processes can be safely terminated, so it would be perfectly possible for `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit` to return a future whose `cancel` terminated the corresponding process. Asyncio coroutines have well-defined cancellation semantics and could automatically make use of it. Unfortunately, `ProcessPoolExecutor.submit` returns a regular [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#future-objects), which assumes the lowest common denominator of the underlying executors, and treats a running future as untouchable.

As a result, to cancel tasks executed in subprocesses, one must circumvent the `ProcessPoolExecutor` altogether and manage one's own processes. The challenge is how to do this without reimplementing half of `multiprocessing`. One option offered by the standard library is to (ab)use [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing.pool) for this purpose, because it supports reliable shutdown of worker processes. A `CancellablePool` could work as follows:

- Instead of spawning a fixed number of processes, spawn a fixed number of 1-worker pools.
- Assign tasks to pools from an asyncio coroutine. If the coroutine is canceled while waiting for the task to finish in the other process, [terminate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.terminate) the single-process pool and create a new one.
- Since everything is coordinated from the single asyncio thread, don't worry about race conditions such as accidentally killing a process which has already started executing another task. (This would need to be prevented if one were to support cancellation in `ProcessPoolExecutor`.)

Here is a sample implementation of that idea:

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing

class CancellablePool:
    def __init__(self, max_workers=3):
        self._free = {self._new_pool() for _ in range(max_workers)}
        self._working = set()
        self._change = asyncio.Event()

    def _new_pool(self):
        return multiprocessing.Pool(1)

    async def apply(self, fn, *args):
        """
        Like multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async, but:
         * is an asyncio coroutine
         * terminates the process if cancelled
        """
        while not self._free:
            await self._change.wait()
            self._change.clear()
        pool = usable_pool = self._free.pop()
        self._working.add(pool)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        fut = loop.create_future()
        def _on_done(obj):
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(fut.set_result, obj)
        def _on_err(err):
            loop.call_soon_threadsafe(fut.set_exception, err)
        pool.apply_async(fn, args, callback=_on_done, error_callback=_on_err)

        try:
            return await fut
        except asyncio.CancelledError:
            pool.terminate()
            usable_pool = self._new_pool()
        finally:
            self._working.remove(pool)
            self._free.add(usable_pool)
            self._change.set()

    def shutdown(self):
        for p in self._working | self._free:
            p.terminate()
        self._free.clear()
```

A minimalistic test case showing cancellation:

```
def really_long_process():
    print("I am a really long computation.....")
    large_val = 9729379273492397293479237492734 ** 344323
    print("I finally computed this large value: {}".format(large_val))

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    pool = CancellablePool()

    tasks = [loop.create_task(pool.apply(really_long_process))
             for _ in range(5)]
    for t in tasks:
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(t, 1)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print('task timed out and cancelled')
    pool.shutdown()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Note how the CPU usage never exceeds 3 cores, and how it starts dropping near the end of the test, indicating that the processes are  being terminated as expected.

To apply it to the code from the question, make `self._lmz_executor` an instance of `CancellablePool` and change `self._loop.run_in_executor(...)` to `self._loop.create_task(self._lmz_executor.apply(...))`.

Comment: This is wonderful and works just as I wanted. It's a shame that asyncio library doesn't actually terminate processes run within ProcessPoolExecutor. It makes sense for ThreadPoolExecutor. I will reserve such a discussion for the Python mailing list perhaps. Thanks.

Comment: @Darkfish I think it would be a worthwhile suggestion for the Python bug tracker. (Though realistically it might be ignored unless accompanied by a patch implementing it.) Also, be careful before using tihs in production. My first attempt was to use `ProcessPoolExecutor` as the underlying pool, but that class was **very** unhappy when someone terminated the pool with a pending tasks - its management thread started raising "bad file descriptor" and similar exceptions, and they couldn't be caught. `multiprocessing` handles it gracefully, but I'm not sure anyone actually tests that.

Comment: Good to know. For now I am only implementing a research prototype, so I suppose will have to test it thoroughly before release. Perhaps when I am over this, I shall look into either patching or at least starting a discussion on Python list. Thanks mate.