# Custom non-blocking operations in Python asyncio

Tags: python-asyncio, nonblocking

Currently, [asyncio Event Loop](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html) supports non-blocking work with network sockets, files, subprocesses, and signals. For other operations, documentations describes [executing code in thread or process pools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools), but that seems much less efficient (threads vs coroutines).

Is there a way to introduce additional *low-level* non-blocking operations, e.g. wrapping I/O-heavy library calls? What primitives must be implemented?

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of low-level call you'd like to introduce? Is the underlying call asynchronous itself? If so, does it provide a notification mechanism or is the caller expected to poll it for completion?

Comment: No, the underlying library call is blocking. I'm thinking of the non-blocking interface extension to introduce, so it's compatible with asyncio. For the sake of definiteness, let's consider [Windows Overlapped Serial port communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff802693.aspx#serial_topic4) as example of non-blocking interface.

Comment: If the underlying library is blocking and you want to wrap it (rather than reimplement it), then threads might be your only option.

Comment: I have control over the library code, so I can extend the interface with non-blocking calls. But I totally miss what calls are expected by `asyncio`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most event loops, the asyncio event loop is built around polling IO sources, file descriptors on Unix and file handles on Windows. *Poll* or *select* is an IO operation that efficiently monitors multiple file descriptors, suspending the current thread until something interesting happens, e.g. new data arrives. Optionally, polling accepts a timeout, so execution can continue even if there is no new IO event. For a more detailed treatment of the topic, refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51177895/1600898) and other answers to the same question.

The poll-based design allows asyncio to natively support two kinds of events:

- IO possible
- timeout expired

All other types of events must be expressed in terms of those two. For example, [`call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.call_soon_threadsafe) wakes up the event loop by writing into an internal pipe monitored by the event loop. The implementation of [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) uses `call_soon_threadsafe` to inform asyncio that the synchronous function has completed.

To connect an entirely different polling mechanism to asyncio, one would typically spawn a thread dedicated to that kind of polling, and use `call_soon_threadsafe` to inform asyncio of new events. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52938384/1600898), for example, shows how to connect the raw multiprocessing pool (which can be terminated) to asyncio.