# Raspberry PI zero w PIR send to Telethon

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, telegram, telethon, raspberry-pi-zero

i try to send the image from a usb webcam to a telegram group if motion is detected.
the motion works, but i cant get it to send it to my group. so im working on to send a text instead. (with the picture i can figure out, but first i need to get the text working)

code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from telethon import TelegramClient
 
SENSOR_PIN = 17
 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN)


#Telegram settings
api_id='xxxxx'
api_hash='xxxxx'
phone='xxxx'

#Kamera Gruppe
chatid = -xxxxx

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)


async def mein_callback(channel):
    print('motion detected!')
    await client.send_message(chatid, 'motion detected')
    
try:
    GPIO.add_event_detect(SENSOR_PIN , GPIO.RISING, callback=mein_callback)
    while True:
        time.sleep(100)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Beende...")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

error:

sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'mein_callback' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the RPi library works, but I know Telethon is an `async` library, and from the looks of it, `RPi` is not.

You cannot use `time.sleep()` because that will block the entire `asyncio` event loop. You would need something like `await asyncio.sleep()`. It also seems you are never running `client.start()`, so the client won't be connected, so `client.send_message` would fail. I recommend you [read through the `asyncio` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to understand this better. That said... the following *should* work, assuming `RPi` is not threaded:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import asyncio
from telethon import TelegramClient
 
...

client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

async def mein_callback(channel):
    print('motion detected!')
    await client.send_message(chatid, 'motion detected')

def schedule_mein_callback(channel):
    client.loop.create_task(mein_callback(channel))  # <- create a new task that will run in the future

async def main():
    async with client:  # <- start the client so `send_message` works
        GPIO.add_event_detect(SENSOR_PIN , GPIO.RISING, callback=schedule_mein_callback)  # <- not an async callback, GPIO can run it fine
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(100)  # <- no longer blocks, telethon can run fine

try:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())  # <- enter async-land
except KeyboardInterrupt:  # <- should generally be used before entering `async`
    print ("Beende...")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: i get another error now:

`
    client.loop.create_task(mein_callback(channel))  # <- create a new task that will run in the future
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telethon/client/telegrambaseclient.py", line 460, in loop
    return asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/events.py", line 644, in get_event_loop
    % threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'.
`

Comment: That means RPi is using threads and calling your callback from one of them. You will need to wrap the create task call in `call_soon_threadsafe`; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57314061/4759433

Comment: oh ok im new to python, need to read that.